# StreetViewPanoramaView clashes in fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-street-view

i have implemented `StreetViewPanoramaView` in a fragment which is one of few pages in my viewpager.
The issue is that `StreetViewPanoramaView.oncreate(savedInstanceState)` which i haved called in my fragment's `onViewCreated(View v,Bundle saved)` method, clashes with the error below

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition 
cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewPanoramaCamera
```

**this does not happen all the time. sometimes when i swipe back in my viewpager from the fragment and then i swipe again toward the fragment.**

if it clashes when i try to swipe toward the fragment,it will continue to clash from there on. i mean i can't enter the fragment.

How can i solve the error since if i comment the method `StreetViewPanoramaView.oncreate(savedInstanceState)`  my fragment clashes in fragment's method `OnResume()` indicating that `streetviewpanoramaview` is null since i have to call `streetviewpanoramaview.onResume()` in that method

**my fragment method**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  streetView = (StreetViewPanoramaView) view.findViewById(R.id.streetMap);
  streetView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

**my viewpager adapter which contains the fragment**

```
 private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

private CustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  switch (position){
    case 0:
      // fragment 0
    case 1:
      //fragment 1
    case 2:
      //fragment 2
    case 3:
      //fragment 3
    case 4:
      locationFragment = LocationFragment.newInstance();
      locationFragment.setTargetFragment(ArmyFragment.this,400);
      return locationFragment;
  }
  return null;
}
```